# Probability that $10$ random books from a collection of $20$ history and $20$ science fiction contains at least one book of each type; and ...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Let's say Mary is a first grade school teacher and today brings to school 40 different books, 20 of which are books about History and the other 20 books are about Science Fiction.
>
> **Question A.**  Mary chooses randomly 10 books from her stack of 40 books and gives those to Peter as a reward for his performance on yesterdays Math test. Calculate the probability that Peter receives at least one book about History and at least one book about Science Fiction.
>
> **Question B.** Mary decides to share all the 40 books to the 20 students of her class. Each book is given randomly to some student and independently of the other books. Obviously some students will get more books than the others (and some may not get any book at all). Calculate the probability Jane and George not getting any book at all.

Regarding question A, I treat the $40$ books as two groups of similar objects (20 Hist and 20 SF).  I count all of the possible combinations (0 Hist books 10 SF books, 1 Hist book 9 SF books, 2 Hist books 8 SF books etc etc ...) and then I find the ways those combinations can be arranged (by groups of similar objects $\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!}$ where $n = 10$ and $n_1$ is the number of Hist books and $n_2$ is the number of SF books). In the end I divide to find the probability.

For question B, I treat the problem as distributing $40$ non-discrete objects (the books) to $20$ discrete boxes (students). The final result is $\dfrac{C(57,40)}{C(59,40)}$.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @ArsenBerk Regarding question A i treat the 40 books as two groups of similar objects (20 Hist and 20 SF).I count all of the possible combinations (0 Hist books 10 SF books, 1 Hist book 9 SF books, 2 Hist books 8 SF books etc etc ...) and then i find the ways those combinations can be arranged (by groups of similar objects n!/n1!n2! where n = 10 and n1 is the number of Hist books and n2 is the number of SF books). In the end i divide to find the probability.

Comment: @ArsenBerk For question B i treat the problem as distributing 40 non-discrete objects (the books) to 20 discrete boxes (students). The final result is C(57,40) / C(59,40).

Comment: Keep in mind that both the students and books are distinct.  Also, in the first question, you should not count cases in which Peter receives only history books or only science fiction books among the favorable cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that both the books and the students are distinct.

**Question A:**  Mary can choose $10$ of the $40$ books in
$$\binom{40}{10}$$
ways.

If Peter is to receive at least one book about history and at least one book about science fiction, Mary cannot choose only history books or only science fiction books.  There are
$$\binom{20}{10}$$
ways for Mary to choose only history books.  There are also
$$\binom{20}{10}$$
ways for Mary to choose only science fiction books.  Thus, there are
$$\binom{40}{10} - \binom{20}{10} - \binom{20}{10}$$
ways for Mary to select $10$ of the $40$ books for Peter while giving Peter at least one history book and at least one science fiction book.

Thus, the probability that Mary gives Peter at least one history book and at least one science fiction when randomly selecting $10$ of the $40$ books for Peter is
$$\frac{\dbinom{40}{10} - \dbinom{20}{10} - \dbinom{20}{10}}{\dbinom{40}{10}} = 1 - \frac{2 \cdot \dbinom{20}{10}}{\dbinom{40}{10}}$$
where the term that is being subtracted from $1$ is the probability that Peter receives only history books or only science fiction books.

Your method would work, except that you must make sure not to give Peter only history books or only science fiction books.  Thus, the number of favorable cases is
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{9} \binom{20}{k}\binom{20}{10 - k}$$
where the first binomial counts the number of ways of selecting $k$ of the $20$ history and the second binomial counts the number of ways of selecting $10 - k$ of the $20$ science fiction books.  Notice that the summation starts at $1$ and ends at $9$ since Peter receives at least one history book and at least one science fiction book.

**Question B**:  Since there are $20$ possible recipients for each of the $40$ books, Mary could distribute the $40$ books in $20^{40}$ ways (if she did not worry about a fair allocation of the books).  If neither Jane nor George were to receive any books, then there would be $18$ possible recipients for each of the $40$ books, which means Mary could distribute the $40$ books to the other $18$ students in the class in $18^{40}$ ways.  Hence, the probability that neither Jane nor George receives a book is
$$\frac{18^{40}}{20^{40}}$$